# React native USSD Linking

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Looking for a way to send USSD with # sign to the Dialer. I have tried but the pound sign (#) is still not showing on the dialer each time i try.

Used the following code:

```
phoneShare = (number) => {
    let phoneNumber = '';
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') { phoneNumber = `tel:${number}`; }
    else { phoneNumber = `telprompt:${number}`; }
    Linking.openURL("" + phoneNumber + "");
};
```

That is the function that i created and later call on other screens.

Answer (score 2):

I realised i needed to encode the USSD in the above function and then later when i call the function, i will have to decode the component uri: Code below:

Take note of the **tel encoding** on line 3:

```
phoneShare = (number) => {
    let phoneNumber = '';
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') { phoneNumber = `tel:${encodeURIComponent(number)}`; }
    else { phoneNumber = `telprompt:${number}`; }
    Linking.openURL("" + phoneNumber + "");
};
```

Later called the function like so:

```
onPress={() => { this.phoneShare(decodeURIComponent(`${this.state.qrvalue}`)) }}
```

And it worked.